# How to resolve package errors in MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am facing version mis match issue in my mvc project.

```
Error   CS1705  Assembly 'System.Web.Http.Cors' with identity 
'System.Web.Http.Cors, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.7.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Http'
with identity 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to nuget package manager and search for `System.Web.Http` upgrade the version and then `clean` and `rebuild` the solution. The issues will be resolved.